# How exactly does intensity (strength) of an electric field influence a charged particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory

- **First of all**, particle is just a point, it has no size, if I understand correctly.
- **The next one** - energy emits and absorbs by portions - quanta; quanta of electromagnetic field are photons with energy *`hw`*.

We have the classic electric field that describes photons, and it has a characteristic - strength, that equals *`F\q`*. One guy from this community explained me, that it isn't a force characteristic, it's an *intensity characteristic*.

So, let's imagine the next situation: particle **A** and particle **B** with same electric charge, situated in some distance from each other, not far. Particle **A** emits photons in all sides(as a **B** particle). Few photons arrives too close to particle **B**. We are sure that it can absorb only *`hw`* energy per time, so what it will do? How long absorbing will goes? Will it absorb another photons which came with absorbed photon?

And, **generally**, if **B** absorb nearest photons, how does it will influence on **B** behaviour, considering that the photons have the same energy, compared to situation, when it absorb only one photon with same energy? It will repel on longer distance, or it will repel with higher acceleration,

[image]

Side question - how often does charged particle radiates photons? In my picture, you can see the interval between oscillations, how does it actually occurs?

Comment: Remember that photons are not always discreet particles. Likewise, 'emission of photons' isn't a regular event.

Comment: @JakobLovern,  by the way, w in hw formula equals (|psi|)^2 ?